# Getting error while taking access of my personal drive rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

connection = GoogleDrive.login("vg123@gmail.com","acbshaka" )

*** GoogleDrive::AuthenticationError Exception: Authentication failed for vg123@gmail.com: Response code 404 for post https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/AuthForInstalledApps

Please Help me I just want to upload csv file to my personal drive from rails code on server side in background process.................Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OAuth instead of it, login is deprecated so long back

[image]